# Unable to extend faker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

I am following instructions from:
http://cloudspace.com/blog/2013/10/18/extending-faker/#.VLdumx9sY8o

My /config/locales/faker.en.yml looks like:

```
en:
  faker:
    girls: 
      first_name: ["priyanka", "Tanya", "aditi", "Tanvi"]
      last_name: ["Acharya", "Agarwal", "Agate", "Aggarwal"]
      name: 
       - "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
```

And I have following: /lib/faker/girls.rb looks like:

```
module Faker
  class Girl < Base
    class << self
      def first_name
        parse('girls.first_name')
      end

      def last_name
        parse('girls.last_name')
      end

      def name
        fetch('girls.name')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Right after starting rails console I run: require Rails.root.join 'lib/faker/girls' to which a true is returned.

After that running following commands do not work as expected.

Output:

```
2.1.1 :004 > Faker::Girl.first_name  => "" 
2.1.1 :005 > Faker::Girl.last_name  => "" 
2.1.1 :006 > Faker::Girl.name  => "\#{first_name} \#{last_name}"
```

Please help me find where I went wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed `parse` and `fetch` up: simple properties are to be `fetch`ed while composed are to be `parsed`. Another glitch is that your class name should correspond the yml (by convention):

```
#         ⇓
class Girls < Base
  class << self
    def first_name
     #⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ it is a simple property 
      fetch('girls.first_name')
    end

    def last_name
     #⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ it is a simple property 
      fetch('girls.last_name')
    end

    def name
     #⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ it is a composed property 
      parse('girls.name')
    end
  ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: mudasobwa can you tell me how to use same variables for email as well.. I have added a property as 
- "#{first_name}.#last_name<at>domain<dot>com" 

but this uses different set of first name and last name. thanks in advance..

Comment: Generally speaking you should `fetch` the variable once. `fetch` (surprisingly) fetches the random value from the given input. Fetch it, save it somewhere and use it.